# Button onClick does not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm new to reactjs. I called this libraries in head tag:

```
    <script src="react/build/react.js"></script>
<script src="react/build/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/15.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="chat-component.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

and this is my react code:

```
var ChatApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        messages: [],
        socket: window.io('http://localhost:3000')
    }
},
componentDidMount: function () {
  var self = this;
    this.state.socket.on("receive-message", function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        self.setState({messages: self.state.messages.push(msg)})
    });
},
render: function () {

    return (

        <div>
            <input id="message" type="text"/>
            <button type="button"  onClick={this.submitMessage} id="demo" value="send">send</button>
        </div>
    )
},
submitMessage: function () {

    var message = $('#message').value;
    // this.socket.emit("new-message", message);
     console.log(message);    
},

});

ReactDOM.render(
<ChatApp />,
document.getElementById("chat")
);
```

Why Button onClick does not working in my code? also in inspector, onClick does not exist :

```
<button type="button" id="demo" value="send">send</button>
```

I know my question is repeated but I really don't find its solution.

Comment: In this scenario, I'd suggest not using jQuery only because you can achieve what you want without it. You can add an `onChange` to your input so that you can update the state as the user types. Once the button is clicked, you can then simply just reference the value in your state. Here's the classical example from the reactjs docs: https://codepen.io/ericnakagawa/pen/QKkJva?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `submitMessage` function above `render`.

When `render` executes, `this.submitMessage` should be defined. In your code, it is defined only after `render`. So, It won't be called. And use `val()` to get the value from the textbox using jQuery

```js
var ChatApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        messages: [],
    }
  },
  submitMessage: function () {

    var message = $('#message').val();
    // this.socket.emit("new-message", message);
     console.log(message);    
  },
  render: function () {

      return (

          <div>
              <input id="message" type="text"/>
              <button type="button"  onClick={this.submitMessage} id="demo" value="send">send</button>
          </div>
      )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
<ChatApp />,
document.getElementById("chat")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat"></div>
```

Comment: before, submitMessage() was render() before. I tested many ways. ):

Comment: @Digipng Updated the answer! Checknow!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that are preventing your code from working as you want:

i. I believe the methods should go inside the first argument to React.createClass.
Try 
`var ChatApp = React.createClass({
   componentDidMount: function () {
     ...
   },
   ...`

instead.

ii. `$('#message')` will return as array of jquery elements that match your selection.
To see this, `console.log(message)`, instead of `console.log(message.value)`. There are two basic ways to solve this: either extract the first element from the array then inspect it's value, or use the `.val()` method on the selected jQuery object, which will return the value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

See [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5QDfORul7bRQ98g8tQzW?p=preview) for working example